# How do I populate end tags using sed, awk or any other command?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a `txt` file that looks like this:

```
<sss>ss<
```

or

```
<firstword>anotherword<
```

I want it to look like this

```
<sss>ss</sss>
```

or

```
<firstword>anotherword</firstword>
```

Basically taking the first word and placing it in an end tag.

And before you asked what I have tried, the answer is nothing, I couldn't think of anything.

Comment: What's "the first word" to you? Is this your actual input or are there additional specifics? Is `sed` a requirement, or can something else be used?

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the question. I hope your understand now.

Comment: [Further reading on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With input:

```
<abc>def<
<firstword>anotherword</firstword>
<ghi>klm<
```

Use:

```
sed 's/<\([^>]*\)>\(.*\)<$/<\1>\2<\/\1>/' input
```

Output:

```
<abc>def</abc>
<firstword>anotherword</firstword>
<ghi>klm</ghi>
```

The sed line only affects lines ending in `<` (because of the `<$`) and catches the patterns between the first `<>` pair and between '><' and pastes everything back in duplicating the first pair at the end (plus a closing '>')

Comment: `<this>will >break your regex<`

Comment: @evilsoup the OP obviously did not have those kind of entries, but the pattern is easily adapted to handle that.

Comment: A little correction to be more correct and short `sed 's/<\([^>]\+\)>[^<]*<$/&\/\1>/'` And if there are no only one pattern in line `sed -E 's/(<([^> ]+)>[^<]*<)(\W|$)/\1\/\2>\3/g'` == that mean *tag's autoclose*

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128967).

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay I know you cannot parse html or CSV in all their glory with sed, you need a parser for that. But the OP doesn't have proper HTML/XML in the first place, so a real parser will barf without end.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a perl approach, essentially the same as Anthon's `sed` solution:

```
$ perl -pe 's/<(.+)>(.+)</<$1>$2<\/$1>/' file
<sss>ss</sss>
```